# Countdown in React: update state or use a reference on a div?

Tags: reactjs, state

I want to implement a countdown that will decrease every second. I've done it using the state but now I'm thinking it's maybe a bad use of the state, maybe it's too much.

Wouldn't it be better to add a ref on a div and manipulate the DOM directly in JS to push the new value every second instead?

Thank you.

Comment: No. What do you see as the benefit? It subverts React mechanisms, goes against the React docs regarding refs, adds code complexity, and makes testing harder than it needs to be. If you're going to do that why bother with React?

Comment: @DaveNewton Since that information is for displaying only, I was thinking maybe it's less consuming to use pure JS for this case.

Comment: What do you think is React for?